# In this income management My edit_record funciton not working

Tags: c, struct, file-handling

When I  try to edit record  This program write aa new record to file instead of editing existing record.
This code work fine except editing existing record.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct taxpayer
{
    char name[50];
    int Pancard_Number;
    int Mobileno;
    float income;
    float tax;
};

void add_record(FILE *file)
{
    struct taxpayer record;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", record.name);
    printf("Enter 5-digit Pancard_number: ");
    scanf("%d", &record.Pancard_Number);
    printf("Enter Mobileno: ");
    scanf("%d", &record.Mobileno);
    printf("Enter income: ");
    scanf("%f", &record.income);

    if (record.income <= 25000)
    {
        record.tax = 0;
    }
    else if (record.income > 25000 && record.income <= 50000)
    {
        record.tax = (record.income - 25000) * 0.05;
    }
    else if (record.income > 50000 && record.income <= 75000)
    {
        record.tax = 1250 + ((record.income - 50000) * 0.2);
    }
    else if (record.income > 75000 && record.income <= 100000)
    {
        record.tax = 5520 + ((record.income - 75000) * 0.3);
    }
    else
    {
        record.tax = 11250 + ((record.income - 100000) * 0.4);
    }

    // record.tax = record.income * 0.1; // 10% tax rate
    fwrite(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file);
    printf("Record added successfully.\n");
}

void show_allrecord(FILE *file)
{
    // rewind(file);
    struct taxpayer record;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s  \n", "Name", "PancardNo.", "Income", "TaxPaid");
    while (fread(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file))
    {
        printf("%-20s %-19d Rs.%-19.2f Rs.%-17.2f  \n", record.name, record.Pancard_Number, record.income, record.tax);
    }
}

void search_record(FILE *file)
{
    // char name[50];
    int search;
    struct taxpayer record;
    printf("Enter pancard number to search: ");
    scanf("%d", &search);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while (fread(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file))
    {
        if (record.Pancard_Number == search)
        {
            printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s  \n", "Name", "PancardNo.", "Income", "TaxPaid");

            printf("%-20s %-19d Rs.%-19.2f Rs.%-17.2f  \n", record.name, record.Pancard_Number, record.income, record.tax);

            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Record not found.\n");
}

// void edit_record(FILE *file)
// {
//     char name[50];
//     struct taxpayer record;
//     printf("Enter name to edit: ");
//     scanf("%s", name);
//     fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
//     while (fread(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file))
//     {
//         if (strcmp(record.name, name) == 0)
//         {
//             printf("Enter new income: ");
//             scanf("%f", &record.income);

//             if (record.income <= 25000)
//             {
//                 record.tax = 0;
//             }
//             else if (record.income > 25000 && record.income <= 50000)
//             {
//                 record.tax = (record.income - 25000) * 0.05;
//             }
//             else if (record.income > 50000 && record.income <= 75000)
//             {
//                 record.tax = 1250 + ((record.income - 50000) * 0.2);
//             }
//             else if (record.income > 75000 && record.income <= 100000)
//             {
//                 record.tax = 5520 + ((record.income - 75000) * 0.3);
//             }
//             else
//             {
//                 record.tax = 11250 + ((record.income - 100000) * 0.4);
//             }

//             // record.tax = record.income * 0.1;
//             fseek(file, -sizeof(struct taxpayer), SEEK_CUR);
//             fwrite(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file);
//             printf("Record updated successfully.\n");
//             return;
//         }
//     }
//     printf("Record not found.\n");
// }






FILE *delete_record(FILE *file) {
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter the name of the taxpayer to delete: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    struct taxpayer record;
    int found = 0;

    // Create a temporary file
    FILE *temp = fopen("temp.txt", "wb");

    // Read each record from the file and write to the temporary file except for the one to be deleted
    while (fread(&record, sizeof(record), 1, file) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(record.name, name) == 0) {
            found = 1;
        }
        else {
            fwrite(&record, sizeof(record), 1, temp);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(temp);

    if (found) {
        // Delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the original file name
        remove("taxpayers.txt");
        rename("temp.txt", "taxpayers.txt");
        printf("Taxpayer with name %s has been deleted.\n", name);
    } else {
        printf("Taxpayer with name %s not found.\n", name);
        remove("temp.txt");
    }

    // Open the original file for appending
    file = fopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab+");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return file;
}


int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab+");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("\n1. Add New Record\n");
        printf("2. List All Tax Payer along with Income Tax to be paid\n");
        printf("3. Search\n");
        printf("4. Edit\n");
        printf("5. Delete Record\n");
        printf("6. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            add_record(file);
            break;
        case 2:
            show_allrecord(file);
            break;
        case 3:
            search_record(file);
            break;
        case 4:
            edit_record(file);
            break;
        case 5:
            delete_record(file);
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 6);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I want that is it update existing record from file .
Also it ask user to enter name whom income you want to update.
I want that it ask for pancard number and match record according to pancard number and updaate record.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. Please don't add unrelated tags, only pick the tag of the language you're actually use.

Comment: Sorry for this This is my first question on this platform

Comment: OT: Please note that passing an input-only stream to `fflush` (like you do with `fflush(stdin);`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as leading to *undefined behavior*. It's supported by a single system with a single compiler as a non-standard and non-portable extension. Using it is a bad habit, please learn *not* to use it.

Comment: As for this site, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Please provide   answere ..

Comment: Posting of the question is enough. No need to add nagging comments. All I try to do is help you write better questions., and tell you about a bad beginners habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Microsoft `fopen` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170) says:

> When a file is opened by using the `"a"` access type or the `"a+"` access type, all write operations occur **at the end of the file**. The file pointer can be repositioned by using fseek or rewind, but is always moved back to the end of the file before any write operation is performed. Therefore, **existing data can't be overwritten**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

That explains your behavior in full: You can't use the `"a"` or `"a+"` specifications if you want to modify data in-place.

To do that you need the `"r+"` specification. Which will fail if the file doesn't exist, so then you need to try again using `"w+"`.

In the future remember that `"a"` means **append**, i.e. add to end.